# How to get google map searched location lat & long in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have used following code to call Google Maps which is installed in Blackberry device

```java
public void invokeGMaps(GMLocation l) {

    URLEncodedPostData uepd = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
    uepd.append("action", "LOCN");
    uepd.append("a",
       "@latlon:" + l.getLatitude() + "," + l.getLongitude());
    uepd.append("title", l.getName());
    uepd.append("description", l.getDescription());
    String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?" + uepd.toString() };
    ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
    ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
    try {
        ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);
    } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Dialog.alert("error1 " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("error2 " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this is working fine. I have passed current postion to it.

Suppose user will search any particular location on google maps after going on google maps. so while returning back to application i want searched location latitude & longitude from google maps.

So please give me idea how i will get it in my application from google maps application?
Please help me, or any help regarding search location on blackberry how to done it?

Thanks for reading my question patiently.

Comment: I didn't even know Google Maps for BB had an API. Unless they implemented a GlobalEvent broadcast, I doubt you can get this info back.